# Stop Mathematica from blinking / flashing after calculation finished

Tags: front-end, customization, linux

I am running Mathematica 12.1 on Manjaro and Ubuntu. I have a frequently recurring bug that causes a notebook to start blinking in the taskbar after finishing an evaluation, regardless of my workspace, until I close down the notebook completely. The blinking will continue regardless of what I do. This is starting to annoy me, so I am looking for a way to turn this setting off, but I cannot find anything in the settings.

I am using XFCE on both systems.

Playing around a bit (on the Ubuntu system), I figured out what is triggering the bug:

- Start an evaluation
- Click on another window on the same workspace to put that window in focus
- Change workspace

Now the blinking will be persistent. If I switch directly to another workspace without first putting another window in focus, the bug does not seem to appear.

I also found a way of rectifying it without having to close down the notebook.

- Start an evaluation
- Change workspace without clicking on any other window
- Wait for evaluation to finish and then click on the blinking notification in the taskbar

Comment: What window manager are you using, do you know? Does it blink after any evaluation at all, like `2+2`?

Comment: Yes, it happens after any evaluation, as long as it does not finish before I manage to switch workspaces, of course. I added some more details in the question.

Comment: If you are describing what I think you are describing, evaluating the following should stop that from happening. `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "EvaluationQueueActions"] = {}`

Comment: @ihojnicki this worked, thanks! Please put it as an answer, and mention that it is available in the Options inspector under Global Options -> System configuration